# Android Navigating through map

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

In the below code, when I switch location using the location control, the background of the map turns black. How can I get the display of the map view back?

```
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
        {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
            {
                if(loc!=null)
                {

                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());

                    try
                    {
                        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude() / 1E6, loc.getLongitude() / 1E6, 1);
                        String add = "";
                        if (addresses.size() > 0)
                        {
                            for (int i =0;i<addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex();i++)
                            {
                                add += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
                            }
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), add, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                    catch(IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                    p = new GeoPoint((int)(loc.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                            (int)(loc.getLongitude() * 1E6));

                    mc.animateTo(p);
                    mc.setZoom(18);
                }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
            {

            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
            {

            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
            {

            }

        }
```

Comment: So how can i get the diplay of the map view back....

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of things that might be causing the map to go black or the entire screen to go black (i.e unresponsive) since you haven't mentioned whether the map only goes black or the screen becomes unresponsive I'm going to assume the screen becomes unresponsive:

1.) You haven't initialized your MapController mc. Do that if you haven't.

2.) This line of code doesn't seem right:

```
 List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                           loc.getLatitude() / 1E6, loc.getLongitude() / 1E6, 1);
```

The reason why I suspect this code is wrong is because loc.getLatitude() will return you a latitude in the form of degrees (something like 18.9647 so if you divide it by 1E6 you are going to get an extremely small number which I suspect isn't what you had in mind so don't divide by 1E6.

Comment: The screen is responding fine but the map goes black..!:(

Comment: With some longitude and latitude values the map view works fine doesn't show black screen so how should i solve that bug?

Comment: That's probably because in some cases the latitude and longitude you are using are invalid

Comment: thanks vishwa the application is working fine now. Just had problem with longitude and latitude values but have fixed the bug.

Comment: Could you accept my answer if you have solved your issue? You can do so by clicking the green tick mark on the upper left corner of my answer.